# I want to compile my java file using php but it shows that javac is not recognised as a command

Tags: java, php

```
<?php  echo shell_exec("javac test.java 2>&1");
echo exec("java test 2>&1");
?>
```

The above code shows the following error:
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Help me resolve this please. I need to upload this on my website..don't know how to install jdk on that or is it pre installed?

Comment: My guess is you have the JRE runtime, but not the JDK.  You need to ensure the JDK is installed and in the class path of the machine running this script.

Answer (score 1):

install JDK and add jdk bin to the `PATH` enviorenment variable

or

run this command it will solve your problem

```
<?php  
echo shell_exec(set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin);//your path to jdk bin
echo shell_exec("javac test.java 2>&1");
echo exec("java test 2>&1");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, check and add the java bin folder from the SDK to the `PATH` environment variable.
If you are on unix system check if the JDK (Sun or OpenJDK is installed)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set your java path, first set the class path,

or use

```
 change in your environment variables and write like this
name=path
 value=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;
```

or try this

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;//your path to jdk bin
echo shell_exec("javac test.java 2>&1");
echo exec("java test 2>&1");
```

Which is given above  by @lakshman

Answer (score 0):

You need to install jdk.

If you already installed the jdk, then set the environment variable, so your application can find the jdk path to execute javac command